# nginx redirect with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a working proxy server configuration for nginx running on my local machine. It is running in docker, and so is the node.js instance which is serving a local instance of my ghost blog.

Because I have just migrated from an old blog engine my urls are now different so I want to configure nginx to return 301 (permanent) redirects to the new url scheme. I have tried using both `rewrite` and `proxy_redirect` and in both cases I get 401 errors. Here is my default.conf

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
server {
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 503;
}
upstream localhost {
    server 172.17.0.3:2368;
}
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
#        rewrite "^/archive/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.+)\.(?:aspx|html)$" /$1 break; 
        proxy_pass http://localhost;
#        proxy_redirect "-*/archive/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.+)\.(?:aspx|html)" /$1;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment either the rewrite or proxy_redirect directives nothing happens - the request gets forwarded to node.js and I get a 404.

If I use multiple location directives like this:

```
location /archive/ {
    rewrite "^/archive/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.+)\.(?:aspx|html)$" /$1 break; 
}    
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost;
}
```

I get a 404 from nginx and the request never makes it to node.js.

Comment: Your `rewrite` in a separate location block, should use `last` instead of `break`. `proxy_redirect` does not rewrite requests. But I can't see anything wrong with either of your rewrite approaches, unless of course the regex is wrong. You could try `rewrite_log on;` to log the rewrites step by step.

Comment: changing the separate location block to `last` worked! I've also tried it all as a single location block as well and that worked too. If you'll post an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rewrite` in a separate location block, should use `last` instead of `break` (See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details):

```
location /archive/ {
    rewrite "^/archive/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.+)\.(?:aspx|html)$" /$1 last;
}
```

`proxy_redirect` does not rewrite requests, it rewrites 3xx responses from the upstream. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

I can't see anything wrong with either of your `rewrite` approaches, unless of course the regex is wrong. You could try adding `rewrite_log on;` to log the rewrites step by step. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log) for details.